# Concavity of function $F(x) = x^{1/5} (x+6)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was wondering when this function would curve upwards/downwards. I was having trouble finding the inflection points. Thank you.

$$F(x) = x^{1/5} (x+6)$$

#### Progress

I found the first derivative to be $\frac65 (x+1)  x^{4/5}$ and the second derivative to be $\frac{6}{25}(x-4) x^{9/5}$. Is that right?

Comment: Have you calculated the first and second derivatives, and tried to see where the second derivative is positive or negative?

Comment: I found the first derivative to be 6(x+1)/5x^(4/5) and the second derivative to be 6(x-4)/25 x^(9/5). Is that right?

Comment: Yes. It's good that you factored the second derivative. Now for what values of $x$ is $F''(x)$ positive? Negative? Zero? That will tell you the concavity.

Comment: Alright but that's where my problem seems to lie. I'm getting that the critical points for this derivative are x=0 and x=4. Is that correct?

Comment: No, now what you wrote for your derivatives is wrong. Would you show how you calculated the first derivative?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $F$ is curving upward is the same as $F$ is increasing, and this is equivalent to $F'(x) > 0$, and curving downward is equivalent to $F'(x) < 0$. I think you mean $F$ is concave up, then you need $F''(x) > 0$, and concave down means $F''(x) < 0$, and inflection point is where $F''(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding the zeroes of the second derivative. Then, find out if the concavity actually changes at these zeroes. Do this by looking at where the second derivative changes sign; i.e., changes from positive to negative, or from negative to positive.

**Hint**: In your question, the second derivative only has one zero. Find that zero and then determine if the sign of the second derivative changes at that point (goes from positive to negative, or goes from negative to positive). If it does, then you have an inflection point, and you can then determine where the original $F(x)$ is concave up or down based on where $F''(x)$ is positive and negative, respectively.

Comment: If the second derivative is, say, positive, then zero, and then positive again, then you won't have an inflection point. So it's important to look at the sign, not just where the zeros are.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I've edited my answer.